# Handling file names with spaces in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

How to handle files with their names containing spaces in a shell script.

Here is what I am trying

```
    find /abc/xyz -name 'BY567*.csv' | while read fname
    do
        mv "$fname" ./archive/$(basename $fname)-$(date +%Y%m%d-%T)
    done
```

But when I do this it strips of the file name after space. Like if file name is BY567_Test file.csv , it will be changed to BY567_Test-datetimestamp and not BY567_Test file.csv-datetimestamp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put double-quotes arround the end of line and in basename :

```
mv "$fname" "./archive/$(basename "$fname")-$(date +%Y%m%d-%T)"
```

The variables will be interpreted and the spaces should be OK.

Comment: cool, it worked. Can I use the double quotes if I am using sftp to transfer the file to other server? Like in above loop if I am trying to connect to the other server  and then using `put $fname`  as command to transfer the file.

Comment: I think so but, I never try. Try and tell us !